# "Which verb to use in a reporting clause?"

Tags: past-tense, indirect-speech

> Direct: he said, “It used to be a lovely quiet street.”
>   Indirect: he said that it used to be a lovely quiet street.

Why is it not:

> He pointed out that it had used to be a lovely quiet street.

Comment: There is no passive voice here.

Comment: That's not "active x passive voice".  It's about "direct x reported speech".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use "he said" every time you put a sentence into indirect speech.  In fact, you can choose the appropriate verb from a long list.

- he said
- he mentioned
- he pointed out
- he exclaimed
- he declared
- he suggested
- he asked
- he wondered
- he told her
- he replied
- he shouted
- etc.

**Whether you choose one or another verb pretty much depends on context and intonation.**

e.g.

- What about going to the beach?  "He suggested..."
- Yes, we must visit her.  "He agreed..."
- I will never allow anyone to disrespect my daughter!!!  "He declared..."

**Context and intonation will help you choose the right verb.**

Comment: The question seems to be about "used to".

Comment: @V.V.  Somebody had edited the question and it turned out completely different from the original.  It has been fixed.